# Where to put php ini file for DB Creds

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, config

I'm connecting to MongoDB via PHP using https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php .

I've put my DB creds in a mongodb.ini file. It's outside of DocumentRoot as to prevent any user from finding it on a browser.

Right now it's in `/var/www/mongodb.ini`

The file looks like

`username=USERNAME password=PASSWORD uri=URI`

I'm then reading it into a connection.php module as such...

```
    $db_config = parse_ini_file("/var/www/mongodb.ini");

    $uri_options = array("username" => $db_config['username'], "password" =>$db_config['password'], "ssl"=>true);
    $driver_options = array("allow_self_signed" => true);
```

Probably not a big deal, but I don't want to hardcode the actual `/var/www` . Should it even be there, or where would be a better place to put it?

Ideally, I'd like the db_creds to be in `virtual_hosts` so that this could work the same way that `mysqli_connect` does. But - doesn't seem like anything like that exists.

Also, if I keep the actual ini file, then what are good permission to put on it?

Comment: Normally /var/www would be inside the web root, unless you changed the default configuration

Comment: Anyway you could potentially use a relative path to avoid hard coding too much. That would just mean the file must always be in the same location relative to the code which is accessing it

Comment: Sorry, I meant DocumentRoot. My hosts file has it as /var/www/html though

Comment: Ok well that should be ok then, sorry. Easy enough to test

Comment: Yeah, I tested it